# Cyper query for showing the labels on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created 4 user nodes(user is the label here) and 3 contact nodes using the following commands.

```
CREATE (:User {clientType: "individual",    firstName:  "User1", emailID: "User1@YourMail.com"});
CREATE (:User {clientType: "institute",     firstName:  "User2", emailID: "User2@YourMail.com"});
CREATE (:User {clientType: "college",       firstName:  "User3", emailID: "User3@YourMail.com"});
CREATE (:User {clientType: "corporate",     firstName:  "User4", emailID: "User4@YourMail.com"});

CREATE (:Contact {address1: "4, Kashmira Apartments" });
CREATE (:Contact {address1: "503, Neelkanth Corporate Park"});
CREATE (:Contact {address1: "VJTI Institute"});
```

Now when I use 
CALL apoc.meta.graph() or CALL db.schema(), I get the following diagram showing only the labels. [image: Calling db.Schema]

But when I use match syntax(**MATCH (n) RETURN n**) of CQL
we get the diagram showing all of the nodes.

[image: Using Match Syntax of the CQL]

Now my question is how can I show only the labels using CQL? 
Just show only the labels with anything like

```
MATCH (n) RETURN UNIQE lables //This does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

To get node labels use functions labels(); this function return list with all node labels

```
match (n) return labels(n) limit 1;
```

If your goal to get list with all labels in graph then use

```
call db.labels;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That does not return nodes with labels.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher (not [CQL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cqlIntro.html), which is another language) is the neo4j query language. The neo4j Browser is a tool that allows you to enter Cypher queries and visualize the results.

If you are asking how to make the neo4j Browser caption a node with its label(s), you can't. However, since the Browser allows you to assign different colors to  different labels, this is usually not a problem.